# How to put vertical scroll bar in this Open Source Accordion?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to put a scroll bar to my Tkinter application but unfortunately it cannot be applied to the root window which is what I am trying to achieve. I tried putting a scrollbar in this open source Accordion code. But unable to do it.

Tkinter allows only certain widgets and canvas to have a scrollbar.

Source: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580781-metro-accordion-for-tkinter/

```
# author: Miguel Martinez Lopez

try:
    from Tkinter import Tk, Frame, BitmapImage, Label
    from Tkconstants import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import Tk, Frame, BitmapImage, Label
    from tkinter.constants import *

import base64

class Animation(object):
    def __init__(self, w, ticks, config_function, duration=1, interval_time=None, easing_function=None, start_value=0, end_value=1, callback=None):
        self._w = w

        self._tick = 0
        self._total_ticks = float(ticks)

        if easing_function is None:
            self._easing_function = lambda x: x

        self._duration = duration

        if interval_time:
            self._interval_time = int(interval_time * 1000)
        else:
            self._interval_time = int(duration * 1000 / self._total_ticks)

        self._start_value = start_value
        self._end_value = end_value
        self._interval_value = end_value - start_value

        self._config_function = config_function

        self._callback = callback

    def start_animation(self, after=0):        
        if after != 0:
            self.after(int(after*1000), self._animate)
        else:
            self._animate()

    def _animate(self):
        t =  self._tick / self._total_ticks

        value = self._start_value + self._interval_value * self._easing_function(t)
        self._config_function(value)

        self._tick += 1

        if self._tick <= self._total_ticks:
            self._w.after(self._interval_time, self._animate)
        else:
            if self._callback is not None:
                self._w.after(self._interval_time, self._callback)


class Chord(Frame):
    RIGHT_ARROW_ICON = 'I2RlZmluZSBpbWFnZV93aWR0aCAxNwojZGVmaW5lIGltYWdlX2hlaWdodCAxNwpzdGF0aWMgY2hhciBpbWFnZV9iaXRzW10gPSB7CjB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLAoweDYwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweGUwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweGUwLDB4MDMsMHgwMCwweGUwLDB4MGYsMHgwMCwweGUwLDB4MDMsMHgwMCwKMHhlMCwweDAxLDB4MDAsMHg2MCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsCjB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwCn07'
    DOWN_ARROW_ICON = 'I2RlZmluZSBpbWFnZV93aWR0aCAxNwojZGVmaW5lIGltYWdlX2hlaWdodCAxNwpzdGF0aWMgY2hhciBpbWFnZV9iaXRzW10gPSB7CjB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLAoweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweGUwLDB4MGYsMHgwMCwweGUwLDB4MGYsMHgwMCwweGMwLDB4MDcsMHgwMCwweGMwLDB4MDMsMHgwMCwKMHg4MCwweDAzLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAxLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAxLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsCjB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwLDB4MDAsMHgwMCwweDAwCn07'

    def __init__(self, master, title, width, body_background="white", background="#f0f0f0", foreground="#333333", selected_background="#1ba1e2", selected_foreground="white", active_foreground="#0067cb", cursor="hand1"):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, background="white")
        self._title = title

        self._background = background
        self._foreground = foreground
        self._active_foreground = active_foreground
        self._selected_foreground = selected_foreground
        self._selected_background = selected_background

        self._cursor = cursor

        self._right_arrow_icon = BitmapImage(data=base64.b64decode(Chord.RIGHT_ARROW_ICON))
        self._down_arrow_icon = BitmapImage(data=base64.b64decode(Chord.DOWN_ARROW_ICON))

        self._caption = Frame(self, width =width, background=background, padx=2)
        self._caption.pack(fill=X, pady=(0,2))
        self._caption.pack_propagate(False)

        self._icon_label = Label(self._caption, image=self._right_arrow_icon, background=background)
        self._icon_label.pack(side=LEFT)

        self._title_label = Label(self._caption, text=title, bg = background, fg=foreground)
        self._title_label.pack(side=LEFT, padx=4, fill=X)

        self._caption.configure(height= self._title_label.winfo_reqheight())

        self.body = Frame(self, background=body_background)
        self._body_height = None

        self._is_opened = False
        self._is_animating = False

        self._caption.bind('<Button-1>', self._on_click)
        self._title_label.bind('<Button-1>', self._on_click)
        self._icon_label.bind('<Button-1>', self._on_click)

        self._caption.bind('<Enter>', self._on_enter)
        self._caption.bind('<Leave>', self._on_leave)

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self._title

    @title.setter
    def title(self, text):
        self._title = text
        self._title_label.configure(text=text)

    def _on_enter(self, event):
        if not self._is_opened:
            self._down_arrow_icon.configure(foreground=self._active_foreground)
            self._right_arrow_icon.configure(foreground=self._active_foreground)

        self.config(cursor=self._cursor)

    def _on_leave(self, event):
        if not self._is_opened:
            self._down_arrow_icon.configure(foreground=self._foreground)
            self._right_arrow_icon.configure(foreground=self._foreground)

        self.config(cursor="arrow")

    def _on_click(self, event):
        if self._is_animating: return

        self.toggle()

    def open(self):
        if self._is_animating: return

        if not self._is_opened: self._open()

    def _open(self):        
        self.body.pack()
        self.body.pack_propagate(False)

        self._icon_label.configure(image=self._down_arrow_icon, background = self._selected_background)
        self._title_label.configure(foreground= self._selected_foreground, background = self._selected_background)
        self._caption.configure(background = self._selected_background)

        self._down_arrow_icon.configure(foreground=self._selected_foreground)

        if self._body_height is None:
            self._body_height= self.body.winfo_reqheight()

        end_value = self._body_height

        self.body.configure(width=self.winfo_width())
        self._is_opened = True
        self._is_animating = True

        animation = Animation(
            self,
            ticks=16,
            interval_time=0.01,
            start_value=0, 
            end_value=end_value,
            config_function=lambda height: self.body.configure(height=int(height)), 
            callback=self._on_finnish_animation)

        animation.start_animation()

    def _on_finnish_animation(self):
        self._is_animating = False

        if not self._is_opened:
            self.body.pack_forget()

    def close(self):
        if self._is_animating:
            return

        if self._is_opened: self._close()

    def _close(self):
        self._icon_label.configure(image=self._right_arrow_icon, background = self._background)
        self._title_label.configure(foreground= self._foreground, background = self._background)
        self._caption.configure(background = self._background)

        self._right_arrow_icon.configure(foreground=self._foreground)

        start_value = self.body.winfo_height()

        self._is_opened = False
        self._is_animating = True

        animation = Animation(
            self,
            ticks=16,
            interval_time=0.01,
            start_value=start_value, 
            end_value=0,
            config_function=lambda height: self.body.configure(height=int(height)), 
            callback=self._on_finnish_animation)

        animation.start_animation()

    def toggle(self):
        if self._is_opened:
            self._close()
        else:
            self._open()

class Accordion(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, width, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        self._width = width
        self._list_of_chords = []

    def create_chord(self, title, background="white"):
        chord = Chord(self, title=title, body_background=background, width=self._width)
        self._list_of_chords.append(chord)

        if len(self._list_of_chords) == 1:
            chord.pack(fill=X)
        else:
            chord.pack(fill=X, pady=(1,0))

        return chord

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        from Tkinter import Entry, Button, Text
    except ImportError:
        from tkinter import Entry, Button, Text

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("400x300")

    root.configure(background="white")


    # create the Accordion
    accordion = Accordion(root, width=200)
    accordion.pack(pady=10)

    first_chord = accordion.create_chord('First Chord')
    Label(first_chord.body, text='hello world', bg='white').pack()

    # second chord
    second_chord = accordion.create_chord('Second Chord')
    Entry(second_chord.body).pack()
    Button(second_chord.body, text='Button').pack()

    # third chord
    third_chord = accordion.create_chord(title='Third Chord')
    Text(third_chord.body).pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

I want to add a scrollbar where I can keep scrolling vertically if there are lot of chords in the above program.

**EDIT**

What I have tried:

```
 root = Tk()

    canvas = Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
    frame = Frame(canvas, background="#ffffff")
    vsb = Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

    vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    canvas.create_window((4,4), window=frame, anchor="nw")
    frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))

    root.geometry("1080x720")
    root.configure(background="black")
    heading = Label(frame, text = "Welcome", bg = "black", fg = "orange", font = ("Arial Bold", 20))
    heading.pack()

    #Logo
    gif1 = PhotoImage(file = 'logo.gif')
    label1 = Label(frame, image=gif1)
    label1.image = gif1 
    label1.pack()

    #Text1 Properties
    text1 = Label(frame, text = "Please select the file :", bg = "black", fg = "white", font = ("Arial", 15))
    text1.pack()

    # create the Accordion
    accordion = Accordion(frame, width=200)
    accordion.pack(pady=10)
    i = 0
    chords = []
    var1Index = 0

    for pick in tests:
        nChords = accordion.create_chord(tests[i][1])
        populateFunct(nChords, tests[i][1], i)
        i += 1
```

In the above program, I get the "Welcome", "logo" and "text" in one frame and the chords in other frame in a same window(Side by side). I am trying hard to put the chords in the same frame where the welcome, logo and the text is displayed but the chords are by default taking its place in root window though I send the frame to Accordion function. This is what the problem I am facing.
PS: The Accordion function is one as mentioned before.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried to add a scrollbar. There are several examples on the internet, what have you tried? Since you didn't show any effort, this will probably be closed as a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7432

Comment: Well, I have tried the same as mentioned at: stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7432. I tried creating a canvas and then embedding a frame in it. And the adding a scrollbar to the canvas but I get this error:File "testUI.py", line 335, in <module>
    canvas.create_window(window=frame, anchor="nw")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2337, in create_window
    return self._create('window', args, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2303, in _create
    cnf = args[-1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: FYI, I have tried from couple of days, but don't know what would be the right way of doing it.

Comment: As written this question is too broad, since there are two or three ways to solve the problem, and the most common solution has already been written about on stackoverflow. If you need specific help you need to show what you've tried.

Comment: I tried lot of things so couldn't post all of them and posted the base code. Anyway, I will come up with a specific question. Thank you.

Comment: @BryanOakley, Could you please suggest me whats going wrong in my approach?

Comment: It would help if you removed the images from the code. That don't seem necessary to reproduce the problem, and make it more difficult for us to run your code. Also, you haven't defined what `tests` or `populateFunct` or `onFrameConfigure` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you're putting the scrollbar inside the frame that is inside the canvas. The scrollbar needs to be outside of the frame, and also usually outside of the canvas too.

For this specific example, the scrollbar can be in the root window since the root window otherwise only has the canvas.

```
vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
```

The second problem is a bug in `Accordion`. It is ignoring the `parent` parameter. You need to change the `__init__` to the following. Notice the addition of the `parent` parameter to `Frame.__init`:

```
class Accordion(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, width, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)

        self._width = width
        self._list_of_chords = []
```

Other than that, I think the code is probably ok. I can't run your code since you left out several critical parts.

Comment: I have tried that sometime back but still I am getting a frame and a root in a same window separately. I dont know why they are not coming in same frame.

Comment: The problem is Accordion function is not taking the frame parameter. Its always putting the contents in root window.

Comment: @chan: I've updated my answer. This is the danger of using code from the internet that you don't understand. `Accordion` has a bug in it.

Comment: thank you so much for catching that! Finally I am getting everything in frame. Really appreciate your time and help :) Yes, I didn't completely go through the code that I got from Internet. Thought everything is perfect in that code, my bad. Lessons learnt.